# Providing input to command in sub process in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to automate command-line utility that requires inputs at prompt. I have written the below program, but it is not working. Please help.

```
def execute_command_login(command,password,inputParameter=''):
    try:
        command = str(command).split(" ")
        p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin =subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=0)
#         p.stdin.write(password)
        time.sleep(2)
        if(p.stdout):
            p.stdin.write(str(password))
            if(p.stdout):
                p.stdin.write(str(inputParameter))
        out,err = p.communicate(password)
        out = str(out).split("\n")
        out.remove('')
        if(err):
            return err
        else:
            return out
    except:
        print("Error while executing command"+str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
```

Comment: You do not give enough for me to post an answer. But I already have some remarks. 1/ you should **never** try to mix communicate with other subprocess channels read of write: if `communicate` can do, use it alone, else do not use it at all. 2/ some systems/programs can buffer output when using pipes, so you could receive the output of a command only when it dies. 3/ it is common to require password from a device (`/dev/tty` on Unix-like) and not from stdin.

Comment: Thanks for remarks. Providing more details. 1. I have commented communicate also.i will once again try. 2. When I am trying to debug statement by statement it is working fine. 3. Manually I tried at terminal it is working fine. This is on Mac os. Command ask user password at command prompt. Please let me know any other details on command. Thanks once again for remarks.

Answer (score 0):

The Pexcept module will do what you want: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: Tried with Pexpect as well.. still it is expecting input from terminal only.i will share that code, may be I am missing something.